# Azure Service bus Relay with Java

Tags: java, azure, cloud, azure-servicebusrelay, azure-java-sdk

I am trying to have a POC running, with which I can use Azure Service Bus relay with Java as backend.

Azure Service Bus relay allow .NET libraries to integrate. There is no Java library available.

If it is not possible with Java, is there any other alternative with java for relay functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched an answer for your question from MSDN thread [How to relay on premises java web service through service bus?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0258f3d6-f63f-4a25-a6dc-5331c3ad3a73/how-to-relay-on-premises-java-web-service-through-service-bus?forum=windowsazuredevelopment).

> This isn't available in Java. Only WCF Services are able to use Service Bus Relay feature currently.
>
> Some options to workaround this might be:
>
> 1. Create a wrapper WCF service in front of the existing Java Service and register it with Service Bus Relay this way making it available.
> 2. Making this into a Loosely coupled architecture by leveraging the Service Bus features that are available currently for Java, like Queues and Topics.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Comment: yah, I have already seen that. But it was very old comment. I thought, they might have implemented the same till now.

Comment: @VipinSharma Yeah, it's old. But according to the newest doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-relay-overview/, Relay is still available for only WCF. Meanwhile, I searched on GitHub & MS sites, but found nothing for Java.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a Java backend with Relay, but you cannot do the same thing as the WCF backend. You have to create a [hybrid connection](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/) to support scenarios outside of WCF.